# Conditionally Hide Checkbox in row of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having a ton of trouble and I've followed plenty of example codes from people with the same question. Basically I have a gridview and I have a column with checkboxes and another with a linkbutton. I want to hide/disable a checkbox in a row, if the databound linkbutton in the other column isn't null (field isn't empty). I've tried every way of doing this...(lb!=null), (lb.Text!=null)     Also, I have tried finding the controls by Column Number...no luck

What am I doing wrong? (gridview functions normally other than the checkbox hiding feature)

I tried debugging and it seemed that it wasn't getting passed the first if statement (rowtype==...)

.cs:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("LinkButtonPO") as LinkButton;

    if (lb.CommandArgument != null)
    {
      CheckBox cb = e.Row.FindControl("CbPO") as CheckBox;

      if (cb != null)
        cb.Visible = false;

     }
   }
 }
```

.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
     CssClass="Gridview" runat="server" 
     AllowSorting="True"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="Order_ID"
     DataSourceID="OrderHistoryData"  
     HorizontalAlign="Center" 
     EmptyDataText="No Data to Display" 
     Width="785px"
     AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AllowPaging="True"
     PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" GridLines="None" PageSize="20"
     ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonPO" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' OnClick="LinkButtonPO_Click" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Lit") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TemplateField >
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CbPO" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CbPO_CheckedChanged" Visible="true" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The very first row is of Type: Header, so in the first iteration when debugging, it won't pass your IF statement that actually checks for DataRow.   Also, I just went through your code & its working fine for me. The checkboxes were getting Hidden. Please tell what is PO_ID? Is it the Primary Key ? Make sure PO_ID is Not null

Answer (score 0):

[`LinkButton.CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx) is implemented in this way(ILSpy on .NET 4):

```
public string CommandArgument
{
    get
    {
        string text = (string)this.ViewState["CommandArgument"];
        if (text != null)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["CommandArgument"] = value;
    }
}
```

So as often in ASP.NET the property is never `null` but `String.Empty`.

So change

```
if (lb.CommandArgument != null)
    cb.Visible = false;
```

to

```
cb.Visible = lb.CommandArgument.Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this and works for me

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("LinkButtonPO") as LinkButton;
            CheckBox cb = e.Row.FindControl("CbPO") as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null)
                {
                    cb.Visible = false;
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not use Columns and Asp:TemplateField for Linkbutton So use that.